# Vscode C++ debugging by bash script

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to debug a C++ program with VSCode, but I run my program with a bash script.
I tried this:

```
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/bin/bash",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "args": ["-ic" , "run_script"],
    },
```

But I receive

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

And the debugger doesn't connect (though the program is running).
I know there's tasks.json for scripts but I want to debug the C++ program invoked from the script.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think this way you're debugging the `bash` program, not yours.

Comment: @Al.G. I guess that's true, but I want to debug the C++ program invoked by the script. I wonder how to do it, and if I can't maybe a workaround. I have full control on the script, so I can change it according to a workaround

Comment: Then tell the debugger to start your program the way the script does it. E.g. if your script calls `program arg1 arg2`, tell the debugger to run this same command.

Comment: then create an `attach` launch, select the process to debug

Comment: It has some complex setup and argument parsing and creation. How can I attach and debug from the beginning?